# Cron job not logging output - Whenever gem

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, cron-task, whenever

I'm new to cron and started using Whenever gem to perform scheduled tasks. However, sometimes they stall and I have to restart the app for it to pick up again. So, I wanted to inspect the logs to see if there are any exceptions that might cause it.

According to [this wiki](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs), I put a line in my `schedule.rb` setting the output location:

```
set :output, "/var/log/cron.log"
```

But this file is always empty.

I tried doing manually from the terminal `/bin/bash -l -c 'echo "hello" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1'` and it saved `hello` to the log.

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Read the Stack Overflow [`crontab` tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for troubleshooting tips, then [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks,

Comment: did you give write permission to cron.log file ?

Comment: you can also try log/cron.log which will create log file in your rails application  log directory

Comment: what type of job are you trying to log? rake? command?